# st_dump - why is the "path" an array?

Tags: postgis

Looking at the postgis documentation, I read:

For an atomic geometry type (POINT,LINESTRING,POLYGON) a single record is returned with an empty path array and the input geometry as geom.
For a collection or multi-geometry a record is returned for each of the collection components, and the path denotes the **position of the component** inside the collection.

As the path denotes a position, I wonder why it is an array as I simply cannot imagine an example where a position of a component inside a collection occures more than one time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible to have nested collections, and in this case the array makes sense:

```sql
select path, st_asText(geom)  
from st_dump('GEOMETRYCOLLECTION(MULTILINESTRING((1 2,3 4),(3 4,4 5)),MULTIPOINT(1 2,3 4))');


 path  |      st_astext
-------+---------------------
 {1,1} | LINESTRING(1 2,3 4)
 {1,2} | LINESTRING(3 4,4 5)
 {2,1} | POINT(1 2)
 {2,2} | POINT(3 4)
(4 rows)
```